# PHP Network Monitoring

Tags: windows, php, network-monitoring

Is there a way that I can monitor the traffic, Upload/Download **(separately)** using PHP?
I`d like to echo out something like that:

**Upload: 523 GB** | **Download: 25 GB**

This should be based on the System Uptime, so if I restart the computer, the count should restart.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want accurate answers, you need to give more information about your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `ifconfig` from within php and parse out the TX/RX fields.

Another option would be to use the php snmp libraries and query the ifinoctet and ifoutoctet OIDs.

Comment: But the problem is, I need it for Windows (more exactly Windows 7)

Comment: The snmp solution would still work for windows. You'd need to set up the SNMP service if it's already not running.

Comment: Do I need to install something for php? I get a function error.

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function snmpget() in D:\WinServer\xampp\htdocs\network\index.php  on line 12"

Line 12:
$sysname[0] = snmpget($sysip[$i], $snmpcommunity, "sysName.0");

Comment: You need the PHP-SNMP module installed and configured. If this is for production use, Use MRTG, or cacti, or one of the many monitoring programs to do this. Don't home grow it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that parses the RX and TX counters from ifconfig (on a Linux box), those get reset on boot.  The only problem is that it wont be just HTTP traffic, it's a global counter for all traffic on the box.

Comment: Yes, thanks no problem I need the global counter, not only HTTP. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ever consider looking at nagios? Free open source monitoring tool. We use it extensively at work to monitor all sorts of things

Answer (score 0):

I think *mod_cband* could do the trick. I don't know if it works on Hasefroch but you could try it...

Edit: Oh, I see that you need a global counter so ifconfig would be the way. I don't like PHP doing system calls so what about a C daemon writing a log file that would be readed by PHP?

Bye